# Kotlin MyClass.class.java Unresolved reference: java

Tags: android, kotlin

In Java Android we use `MyActivity.class` to start a new activity. I was playing with Android Studio 3 beta1 and tried to convert it to kotlin. It gets converted to `MyActivity::class.java` but this doesn't compile. It gives me `Unresolved reference: java`. What would be the correct equivalent?

Project Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

App Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 104
        versionName "4.0.11"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "mode"

    productFlavors {
        free {
            dimension "mode"
        }
        paid {
            dimension "mode"
            applicationId "app.paid"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
    releaseCompile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.1'
    //    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.github.frangsierra:rx2firebase:1.1.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: what is the error message / logs? Can you post your code snippet?

Comment: MyActivity::class.java is the kotlin version. What are the error logs ?

Comment: Which version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: @Natan I believe it is 1.1

Comment: Which exact version of Android Studio are you working? In my knowledge there is no release named `beta 1` as of now. Its in `Android Studio 3.0 Canary` format.

Comment: Can you provide build.gradle files of both `project level` and `app level`?

Comment: @chandil03 it was released a few hours ago

Comment: Thanks for the update, i am just updating and let you know the status.

Comment: At a first look, i guess you are missing `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3-2"` line in your `project level build.gradle` file.

Comment: I saw that when a created an empty project. It makes no difference.

Comment: I suspect that can be a bug from the update. Have you tried the solution described in the Release Notes?https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html

Comment: @YoshioMYH, yeah a plain Java build wasn'tt possibple without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was an bug. I just updated to beta2 an the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following changes in your gradle file.

Add `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3-2"` in your project build.gradle file.

### build.gradle(:project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3-2" // New 
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

...
...
```

---

And add

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`

two lines in app build.gradle file.

### build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' // New 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' // New 

android {
    ...
    ...

    ...
    ...
}


dependencies {
    ...
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This must solve your problem as i have updated My Android Studio to `3.0 beta 1` and having so issues.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. I even did a clean build. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof dumb thing to ask but still : have you installed kotlin plugin?